# Trouble With Bubble Blaster Python Code?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3

I am working on a project, and have completed the code, yet one error is still showing up, even though I am sure my code is correct.

Here is the error that keeps showing up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\bubblee blaster.py", line 61, in <module>
    clean_up_bubs()
NameError: name 'clean_up_bubs' is not defined
```

Here is my python code:

```
from tkinter import *
HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800
window = Tk()
window.title('bubble blaster')
c = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='darkblue')
c.pack()
ship_id = c.create_polygon(5, 5, 5, 25, 30, 15, fill='red')
ship_id2 = c.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, outline='red')
SHIP_R = 15
MID_X = WIDTH / 2
MID_Y = HEIGHT / 2
c.move(ship_id, MID_X, MID_Y)
c.move(ship_id2, MID_X, MID_Y)
SHIP_SPD = 10
def move_ship(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        c.move(ship_id, 0, -SHIP_SPD)
        c.move(ship_id2, 0, -SHIP_SPD)
    elif event. keysym == 'Down':
        c.move(ship_id, 0, SHIP_SPD)
        c.move(ship_id2, 0, SHIP_SPD)
    elif event.keysym == 'Left':
        c.move(ship_id, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
        c.move(ship_id2, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        c.move(ship_id, SHIP_SPD, 0)
        c.move(ship_id2, SHIP_SPD, 0)
c.bind_all('<Key>' , move_ship)
from random import randint
bub_id = list()
bub_r = list()
bub_speed = list()
MIN_BUB_R = 10
MAX_BUB_R = 30
MAX_BUB_SPD = 110
GAP = 100
def create_bubble():
    x = WIDTH + GAP
    y = randint(0, HEIGHT)
    r = randint(MIN_BUB_R, MAX_BUB_R)
    id1 = c.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x +  r, y + r, outline='white')
    bub_id.append(id1)
    bub_r.append(r)
    bub_speed.append(randint(1, MAX_BUB_SPD))
def move_bubbles():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)):
        c.move(bub_id[i], -bub_speed[i], 0)
from time import sleep, time
BUB_CHANCE = 10
TIME_LIMIT = 30
BONUS_SCORE = 1000
score = 0
bonus = 0
end = time() + TIME_LIMIT
#MAIN GAME LOOP
while time() < end:
    if randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
        create_bubble()
        move_bubbles()
        clean_up_bubs()
        score += collision()
        if (int(score / BONUS_SCORE)) > bonus:
            bonus += 1
            end += TIME_LIMIT
            show_score(score)
            show_time(int(end - time()))
        print(score)
        window.update()
        sleep(0.01)
def get_coords(id_num):
    pos = c.coords(id_num)
    x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
    y = (pos[1] + pos[3])/2
    return x, y
def del_bubble(i):
    del bub_r[i]
    del bub_speed[i]
    c.delete(bub_id[i])
    del bub_id[i]
def clean_up_bubs():
   for i in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
       x, y = get_coords(bub_id[i])
       if x < -GAP:
          del_bubble(i)
from math import sqrt
def distance(id1, id2):
    x1, y1 = get_coords(id1)
    x2, y2 = get_coords(id2)
    return sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
def collision():
    points = 0
    for bub in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        if distance(ship_id2, bub_id[bub]) < (SHIP_R + bub_r[bub]):
            points += (bub_r[bub] + bub_speed[bub])
            del_bubble(bub)
    return points
c.create_text(50, 30, text='TIME' , fill='white' )
c.create_text(150, 30, text='SCORE' , fill='white' )
time_text = c.create_text(50, 50, fill='white' )
score_text = c.create_text(150, 50, fill='white' )
def show_score(score):
    c.itemconfig(score_text, text=str(score))
def show_time(time_left):
    c.itemconfig(time_text, text=str(time_left))
c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y, \
     text='GAME OVER', fill='white', font=('Helvetica' ,30))
c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y + 30, \
              text='Score: '+ str(score), fill='white')
c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y + 45, \
              text='Bonus time: '+ str(bonus*TIME_LIMIT), fill='white')
```

Comment: Basically, you should define functions first, then do the main logic later. It's hard to read when you define a function in the middle of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is an unreadable mess!

You should put all your imports at the top of the script.
Next, define your global constants (and global variables, but it's better if you can reorganize your code to minimize the use of global variables).
Next define your functions.
And then put the code that calls those functions at the end.

The reason for this is that you need to define things before you can use them. Python scans your script top down, creating various objects (including functions) by executing the definitions as it goes. Functions *definitions* can refer to global things (including other functions) that haven't been defined yet. But when you actually *call* the function the things that it refers to **must** have already been defined.

Also, put (at least) one blank line around functions to make it easier to see where they begin and end. And use blank lines elsewhere to make the structure of your program more obvious.

I've tried to implement those changes, and the resulting code runs, but I'm not sure if it does exactly what you want.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
from time import sleep, time
from math import sqrt

HEIGHT = 500
WIDTH = 800

SHIP_R = 15
MID_X = WIDTH / 2
MID_Y = HEIGHT / 2

SHIP_SPD = 10

bub_id = list()
bub_r = list()
bub_speed = list()
MIN_BUB_R = 10
MAX_BUB_R = 30
MAX_BUB_SPD = 110
GAP = 100

BUB_CHANCE = 10
TIME_LIMIT = 30
BONUS_SCORE = 1000

score = 0
bonus = 0
end = time() + TIME_LIMIT

def move_ship(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        c.move(ship_id, 0, -SHIP_SPD)
        c.move(ship_id2, 0, -SHIP_SPD)
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        c.move(ship_id, 0, SHIP_SPD)
        c.move(ship_id2, 0, SHIP_SPD)
    elif event.keysym == 'Left':
        c.move(ship_id, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
        c.move(ship_id2, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        c.move(ship_id, SHIP_SPD, 0)
        c.move(ship_id2, SHIP_SPD, 0)

def create_bubble():
    x = WIDTH + GAP
    y = randint(0, HEIGHT)
    r = randint(MIN_BUB_R, MAX_BUB_R)
    id1 = c.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x +  r, y + r, outline='white')
    bub_id.append(id1)
    bub_r.append(r)
    bub_speed.append(randint(1, MAX_BUB_SPD))

def move_bubbles():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)):
        c.move(bub_id[i], -bub_speed[i], 0)

def get_coords(id_num):
    pos = c.coords(id_num)
    x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
    y = (pos[1] + pos[3])/2
    return x, y

def del_bubble(i):
    del bub_r[i]
    del bub_speed[i]
    c.delete(bub_id[i])
    del bub_id[i]

def clean_up_bubs():
   for i in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
       x, y = get_coords(bub_id[i])
       if x < -GAP:
          del_bubble(i)

def distance(id1, id2):
    x1, y1 = get_coords(id1)
    x2, y2 = get_coords(id2)
    return sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)

def collision():
    points = 0
    for bub in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        if distance(ship_id2, bub_id[bub]) < (SHIP_R + bub_r[bub]):
            points += (bub_r[bub] + bub_speed[bub])
            del_bubble(bub)
    return points

def show_score(score):
    c.itemconfig(score_text, text=str(score))

def show_time(time_left):
    c.itemconfig(time_text, text=str(time_left))

window = Tk()
window.title('bubble blaster')
c = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='darkblue')
c.pack()
ship_id = c.create_polygon(5, 5, 5, 25, 30, 15, fill='red')
ship_id2 = c.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, outline='red')

c.bind_all('<Key>' , move_ship)

c.move(ship_id, MID_X, MID_Y)
c.move(ship_id2, MID_X, MID_Y)

c.create_text(50, 30, text='TIME' , fill='white' )
c.create_text(150, 30, text='SCORE' , fill='white' )
time_text = c.create_text(50, 50, fill='white' )
score_text = c.create_text(150, 50, fill='white' )

#MAIN GAME LOOP
while time() < end:
    if randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
        create_bubble()
        move_bubbles()
        clean_up_bubs()
        score += collision()
        if (int(score / BONUS_SCORE)) > bonus:
            bonus += 1
            end += TIME_LIMIT
            show_score(score)
            show_time(int(end - time()))
        #print(score)
        window.update()
        sleep(0.01)

c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y, \
     text='GAME OVER', fill='white', font=('Helvetica' ,30))
c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y + 30, \
              text='Score: '+ str(score), fill='white')
c.create_text(MID_X, MID_Y + 45, \
              text='Bonus time: '+ str(bonus*TIME_LIMIT), fill='white')
```

FWIW, it's not usual to use Tkinter like that, in a loop with `window.update` and `sleep`. It's more normal to use `window.mainloop` and event-driven programming.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Your code worked, and fixed my game! Thanks!

Comment: Yes of course, sorry I'm new here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Right now `clean_up_bubs` is below line 61. You must have it before it is called. You'll notice `move_bubbles` and `create_bubbles` are before the while loop, the same must be true for `clean_up_bubs`.